# how to calculate how much data can be embeded into an image

Tags: steganography

I want to know how much data can be embedded into an image of different sizes.
For example in 30kb image file how much data can be stored without distortion of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the image type , algoridum , if i take a example as a 24bitmap image to store ASCII character

```
To store a one ASCII Character = Number of Pixels / 8 (one ASCII = 8bits )
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on two points:

1. How much bits per pixel in your image.
2. How much bits you will embed in one pixel .

O.K lets suppose that your color model is RGB and each `pixel = 8*3 bits` (one byte for each color), and you want embed 3 bits in one pixel.

`data that can be embedded into an image = (number of pixels * 3) bits`

Answer (score 0):

If you would use the LSB to hide your information this would give 30000Bits of available space to use. 3750 bytes.

As the LSB represents 1 or 0 into a byte that gets values from 0-256 this gives you in the worst case scenario that you are going to modify all the LSBs distortion of 1/256 that equals 0,4%.

In the statistical average scenario you would get 0,2% distortion.

So depends on which bit of the byte you are going to change.